# What is a function signature?

Tags: python, signature

I was studying python and I ran into the concept of 'signature'. I looked things up but signature of a function seems to have different meaning for different languages. So, what does signature of a function refer to in python?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0362/#signature-object

Comment: generally the signature of a function refers to the names and types of the arguments the function accepts, along with the type of its return value

Answer (score 11):

In general the signature of a function is defined by the number and type of input arguments the function takes and the type of the result the function returns.

As an example in C++ consider the following function:

```
int multiply(int x, int y){
    return x*y;
}
```

The signature of that function, described in an abstract way would be the set {int, int, int}.

As Python is a weakly typed language in general the signature is only given by the amount of parameters. But in newer Python versions type hints were introduced which clarify the signature:

```
def multiply(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x*y
```

Comment: This reply is the most accurate. The names of the parameters are not part of signature, as the caller does not need to know them in order to call the function.

Answer (score 3):

The signature indicates the names and types of the input arguments, and (with type annotations) the type of the returned result(s) of a function or method.

This is not particular to Python, though the concept is more central in some other languages (like C++, where the same method name can exist with multiple signatures, and the types of the input arguments determine which one will be called).

Comment: Just a few more questions. Is the name of a function a part of signature? If the number and type of input is the same but the parameter name is different, are they considered different signature?

Comment: I would regard the name as a distinct attribute, and the parameter names as non-essential as far as the signature is concerned, but this also depends on your use case. Compare to the difference between equality (`==` operator) and identity (`is` operator).

Answer (score 0):

A function signature is its declaration, parameters, and return type.

```
def func(params):
    #some stuff
    return modified_params
```

When you call it is an instance of that function.

```
var = func(parameters)
```